# javascript time conversion (seconds-=)

Tags: javascript, time

```
 time -=  50 * 60
```

I am unsure why time-=  is used in the above code snippet? What is the purpose?

Comment: That is there to get the remainder.

Comment: `x -= y` means `x = x - y`.

Answer (score 0):

Hours is equal to the number of hours in the number of seconds rounded down to a whole number. This difference between hours and the precise number of seconds contains an amount between 0 and just below the maximum number of seconds in 1 hour. To get this, the time in Hours is subtracted from the number of seconds. A similar process follows for the number of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain line by line to help you get this point:

```
var seconds = count;  //25 * 60 = 1500 (1)
```

=> just get total seconds before calculating

```
var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
```

=> this is how to calculate hour

```
seconds -=  hours * 3600;
```

=> this code can be written is easy way `seconds =  seconds - (hours * 3600);`
so the result `seconds` in this line is the remain second after calculating `hours`. Now if you get this point the remain code is easily to understand.

```
 var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);  
 seconds -= minutes * 60
```

Now, after running this code you can check the result by:

```
var total_seconds = hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds;
```

The result `total_seconds` must be equal to value of `seconds` in the first line of code (1).

This is the basic of programming. If you cannot understand, try to debug it by `console.log()` to show result. Try yourself is the good way to improve your skill.

```js
var seconds = 7510;  
console.log("seconds: "+seconds);

var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600); 
seconds -=  hours * 3600;
console.log("hour: "+hours);
console.log("seconds after calculating hours: "+seconds);

var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);  
seconds -= minutes * 60;
console.log("minutes: "+minutes);
console.log("seconds after calculating munites: "+seconds);

var total_seconds = hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds;
console.log("total_seconds: "+total_seconds);
```